# How to merge two git repositories

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

We have project, that was cloned into three independent repositories [*production*, *developer1*, *developer2*].

Developer repos are working like (bare+live).

Each developer working with his own repo, and after some time, we desided to merge developers repos, to pull merged version into production. After this, all tree repositories should be identical.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the primary workflow.

You need to transfer all the branches you wish to merge to a single machine, and use the `git merge` command. Afterwards, you end up with a single branch that is a strict successor of the other developers' branches, so they can *fast-forward* to the merged version.

Comment: there is no branches. I wanna merge two independent repos. That were identical some time ago.

Each of developers made different edits in his repo (create new files, delete, edit). So by this moment this developers repos are really  different, and I wanna somehow merge them.

Comment: Each repository has its own "master" branch, and these are the branches you need to merge.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to set up a remote for each of the developer's repos. If you can't access them by network, ask for a copy of their `.git` folder and make a remote to a place on your harddrive that has it. You should have as many remotes as you have developers. In your repo, `git fetch` each repo. If you named each remote by their names, like "johnsmith", you can now see each master branch from their repos. They will look like so: `johnsmith/master`, `janedoe/master`, etc. when you issue the `git branch -r` command to list all the remote tracking branches.

Now you can merge those one by one with a command like

```
git merge orange/johnsmith
```